# other way to "say the most reason"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I want to say that my uncle was the reason .... but I am confused.

"My uncle was the most reason why I am choosing Medicine as my future career."

or it is right ?

Comment: *most important reason*

Comment: "Reason" can't be quantified. Say "the main reason" or, as Deadrat suggests, "most important".

Comment: As collocations go, I'll advise you to phrase it as "My uncle was the biggest reason..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word `most` is the superlative form of `much` and `more`. It is used to express the greatest quantity, size, number, degree or any measurable property of a noun. For example, we can say '`the most important reason`'. Here, '`most`' communicated that the importance of this particular reason is the greatest (in degree/extent). So, most adds weight to the `importance`, not the `reason` itself.
As another example, in 'The cheetahs are the `most` successful in chasing prey', most communicated the highest degree of success.

In your usage, you would do well to use

> most important reason

or one of the following choices which convey the same meaning.

> My uncle was one of the biggest reasons why I am choosing Medicine as
>   my future career.
>
> My uncle greatly influenced my decision to choose Medicine as my
>   future career.

[Note: A lot depends on the context you are using these phrases]

Comment: The answer would be greatly improved by adding *why* "most reason" would be wrong, rather than relying on a bald assertion.

Comment: @AndrewLeach thanks for the suggestion! Implemented it.